# Getting the length of a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

```
int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i <= haystack.length() - needle.length(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < needle.length(); j++){
            if(haystack[i+j] != needle[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == needle.length()){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It's the code I wrote to implement a strStr function. I found it quite strange that when haystack = "" and needle = "a", the result it returns is 32 rather than -1.

However, when I revise the third line into

```
int k = haystack.length() - needle.length();
for(i = 0; i <= k; i++){
```

It returns the correct output -1. Now I am really confused. Why the code I originally wrote is wrong? What's the difference between them?

Comment: The [`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) function returns a `size_type` which is an ***unsigned*** type. Unsigned `0` minus unsigned `1` gives you a very large number. When you assign to a *signed* integer variable, that large number becomes something else.

Comment: As for how I would recommend you solve the problem: Add a check that ensures that `haystack.length() >= needle.length()`. Or, you know, use [the `std::string::find` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
int(haystack.length()) - int(needle.length())
```

Be aware that

```
cout<<(size_t(0)-size_t(1))<<endl;
```

shows

```
18446744073709551615
```